# Cannot interact with Bing Map on iOS; Android does not show polyline (Flex Mobile App, using Javascript API through StageWebView)

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, bing-maps, flex4.5

After being unable to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592185/google-maps-js-api-v3-will-not-load-inside-flex-mobile-stagewebview), I decided to try to implement my application using Bing Maps. I am trying to load a StageWebView with the Google Maps Javascript API inside a Flex Mobile application. Everything works perfectly when I view this in a browser (IE, Chrome and Safari) and in the Flash Builder simulators. On the actual devices I get varying results. I am using the `StageWebView.loadString()` method to load my code in Flex.

The iPhone displays the map and the shapes I put on it but does not allow me to intuitively interact with it (drag the map, zoom by pinching or double-tapping). It also does not display the interactions bar at the top left as it does in a browser.

On an Android phone (and the BlackBerry Playbook), I still cannot interact with the map intuitively, but I get the interactions bar, which mostly works. However, the app will not display my polylines (it does display pushpins).

On both devices, when I tap or doubletap on the map to try to intuitively interact with it, the keyboard comes up. Typing displays no text.

Any ideas on what my be the issue? Will I need to write my own intuitive interaction functions?

Comment: I'd try mapping Flex components from http://flex.org/tour/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Alexander Farber's suggestion, I decided to use [MapQuest's Flex/Flash Mobile API](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as/v/mq/samples/samplesexplorer/index.html), which has proven to be very effective.